# Webpage load too slow only on client

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website deployed in IIS (local network). If I use the IE browser in IIS Server, it takes less than 10 seconds for 1 page.
But if I access from another PC (in local network - 1Gbps). It takes 3~4 minutes. Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks

Comment: First Press F12 and compare the network and performance tab between fast and slow

Comment: I have tried and realize that It took 12s to load a css file 4Kb.

Comment: Handy tool right? I wonder why it isn't cached

Comment: It also fast if i use the browser in another server. So i think the issue is related to client device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it related to driver of my network adapter. It work after I turn off checksum following this post: https://superuser.com/questions/961617/how-to-disable-checksums-on-ethernet-card-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1):

Capture a FREB trace on IIS. Follow this article - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2009/04/01/freb-failed-requests-tracing-in-iis-7/

Under step 2, instead of adding the status code as 404.2 as mentioned in the article, please add 200-999. Also, as the next step, you will have to select trace providers. Select everything here or leave it to default.

Once the rule is enabled, try accessing the application from a client and reproduce the issue. Go back to the location where FREB was saved. If there are multiple files created, be patient and look for the one with the requested page and observe the time it took.

Open this file in IE and click on compact view. On the right hand side, you will see the time spent by the request in each module. Keep scrolling down until you see a jump in time there. The module where you see there is a jump is the culprit in your case.